# How to store multiple-users authorization tokens from a single service if I can't use a persistent storage?

Tags: design, python, web-applications, django

I'm new to "web development" so I don't know much about ways to store data.

I'm trying to build a web app using Python-Django which accesses private data from multiple accounts. The data comes from a [third party eCommerce site](https://mercadolibre.com) and my app is supposed to access it by making HTTP API calls to this service.

This service uses the OAuth2 protocol to grant permissions for third-party apps.

**The flow goes like this:**

1. The data owner logs in to the third-party service
2. Goes to my app website, presses a button and grants permission to access his data.
3. Through a redirection my app captures the authorization code, exchanges it to get authorization and refresh token, 7 days expiry and 6 month expiry respectively according to the API docs.
4. With this tokens my app can perform the API calls to get the owner's data.

**Some considerations:**

1. The user of this app is one single person, an admin user behind all of this. The data owners are not users, they don't have to do anything else than to grant access to their data.
2. I need to perform multiple API calls very quickly to get data from about 20 data owners in less than an hour every day. There could be more data owners in the future.
3. This data needs to be processed, maybe stored in a database and be sent to another application.
4. I need to store these tokens somewhere to be able to do this, the data owners should not have to grant permissions everyday or every time. When they no longer want to access their data they can remove my app from their security panel.

I've done some improvements by now but I face the following issue and don't know what to think.

** The problem **
[terms and conditions](https://developers.mercadolibre.com.ve/es_ar/terminos-y-condiciones) (it's in Spanish but I'll try to translate it) of this third-party API stands that I cannot:

> capture or store User security keys

> Under no circumstances may the Developers collect or store security keys

I guess it's obvious that you cannot access to the user password through the API so I think
that `security keys` refers to API keys. Seems like I cannot store persistently the access token and refresh token, I don't know if I'm understanding or misunderstanding things.

** What I wanted to do before reading terms and conditions **

I though that I could store this API keys in a database, maybe encrypt it, and then retrieve them any time I need, this doesn't seem difficult to do but seems like I can't do it.

** Other workarounds: **

1. Store these keys in-memory: tried to create an empty environment variable, reference it through settings.py and then using it in the view function to store the API keys inside a list of dictionaries.It worked but when the views.py function finishes it's execution I can no longer access it, I don't know if the view, along with the render, should return this modified variable, but then again what can I do with it?.

Remembering that I'm a rookie on this and don't have much IT knowledge I thought that as long as the web server is running this variable will be stored somewhere in-memory and then I could access it, but seems that it's lost after the view execution.

2. Store the keys in local storage, cookies, and other front-end storage types. I must confess I don't know anything about this I just noticed that it is "another way to store access tokens", but I've been doing some research and this kind of storage is not intended to be used this way and I don't understand well how I could store multiple keys this way.
3. Store it in external files: same problem with database storage, files are persistent.

This is an opinion-based question on web development app design. I hope my goal has been understood and the current problem. Maybe I went a little too far with all this "brainstorming" considering that I don't have any background on this but I'm trying to learn how apps are designed.

Comment: This sounds more like a legal issue. If the terms and conditions forbid to store security keys, this probably includes in-memory storage (as long as their isn't made any other definition of "to store" in the terms), so your "solution" is none. What you need is to get a contractual exception for those terms for your use case.

Comment: My guess is that you misunderstand the terms&conditions. Giving out tokens with an expiry period of 7 days/6 months that you are not allowed to store doesn't make sense. I would advise you contact the owners of the 3rd party service to get a clarification.

Comment: I'm glad to read your comments, i've tried to contact them but they are pretty hermetic, they don't have contact forms, emails or anything. They only have a support channel for certificated developers (it's very difficult to obtain that certification). Anyway at least from a technical point of view I'm glad to know that this is pretty much it and there isn't something that I'm missing. Thanks!!

Comment: I second Bart's comment about it being nonsensical to issue 6-month tokens which cannot be stored.    The OAuth2 specification defines the concept of a 'Token' to describe the JWTs used for `access_token` `refresh_token` (and OpenIdConnect by extension also defines `id_token`).   OAuth2 does not define the concept of a 'Key',  Many popular OAuth2 providers do define concepts such as Keys and Secrets in concrete terms which are very clearly *not* the same thing as a Token.   The problem here is that it is unclear whether your API service provider falls into this category.

Comment: For example: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/tenant-settings/signing-keys#how-it-works